# What blocks Barbarian spell casting?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I have been experimenting with Karlach and a Heat build, as she has innate fire resistance. However I often encounter this when trying to use the Heat for extra fire damage.

[image: Legacy of Avernus: Searing Smite 'Casting spells is blocked']

> Casting spells is blocked.

She does not have an effect which blocks spells such as silence. She just has Bull's Strength, Blessing of Selûne, Pixie Blessing, Rage, and Bless.

So what's blocking her spell casting?

[image: Karlach avatar]

*Sorry about the screenshot quality, that's HDR for you*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rage prevents spellcasting, and ends concentration if you already have a spell cast previously.

This means the only spellcasting barbarians can do are those with non-concentration durative effects like Armor of Agathys, False Life, or Mage Armor (and it must be done pre-rage!).

Check the second **!** bullet on the Rage ability itself:

[image: the tooltip of "Rage: Wolf Heart" from Baldurs Gate 3]

(This property is true of all the various flavors of Rage available to the barbarian subclasses)

Comment: I guess I need a weapon which has Fire dmg

Comment: Have you considered dipping your weapons in a candle? (Or other handy source of fire)

Comment: Note: This particular restriction comes from the [rules for the barbarian's Rage feature in the *Dungeons & Dragons* 5th edition tabletop RPG](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#Rage-51).